# What's the correct way to setup swap on 23.04, I'm getting boot errors and crashing during suspend when using default install options

Tags: swap, 23.04

I ran the default install but it created a swap file with only 8gb of space. I believe this is the reason why my laptop would crash when waking from sleep. My ram size is 32GB and I usually have a lot of apps open.

I expanded the size of the swap file to 64GB and reassigned the new UUID, but I'm getting the following errors on boot.

How can I solve this?

[image: boot errors]

Comment: Read `man mkswap swapon fstab`. Your `/swap.img` file Must be contiguous (https://www.pcmag.com/encyclopedia/term/contiguous-file).

Comment: *"I believe this is the reason why my laptop would crash"* - I don't agree with this conclusion. 32GB is enough RAM where it's unlikely that swap is even being utilized unless your RAM needs are actually exceeding 32GB. In fact, you have a lot of errors about orphaned inodes. This typically indicates problems with the file system and is commonly a sign of hard drive failure. A noncontiguous swap file could also be a consequence of drive failure, especially if it's a very large file, because there are more opportunities for it to be affected.